# Are VDM brushes usable in blender?

Tags: zbrush

Is there a converter/importer/native support for VDM brushes?
There are many ZBrush brush libraries in VDM format.

Comment: there tuts videos out there that help maybe with vector mapping..
https://youtu.be/ekaQPkEdudw
I thing the vector sculping brush is not in development no task is in the dev.logs. the fast past developer Paplo is gone..
maybe right click select vote could help again...

Answer (score 1):

There was a [discussion](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/JQfbbc/?sorting=hot) of this on Right-Click Select about a year ago.  Although it has received over 200 votes, at the moment the answer remains no.

Comment: Thank you. Are alpha brushes an alternative? I'm trying to achieve a manifold mesh for 3d printing. So I don't really care about baking. I've had poor results with boolean or mesh displacement modifiers.

Comment: I don't do 3d printing so I'm afraid I can't help you much further on that.  I'd suggest adding a question  about what you're trying to do and what kind of brushes will work.  People with more printing background might be able to help.